# Datas studio community connector: getData is called twice and fields list = null

Tags: looker-studio

I've made a community connector getting my data from Bigquery, and in one specific case, the gatData function is called twice and one of the call does not send fields

This occured when in a dashboard :

- I make a table chart: getData is called once, all is OK
- And just toggle "Show summary row" to True: see my screenshot in attachment, getData is called twice and fields equals to null
  [here is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW7P3.jpg)

Is anyone can explain me if it's a bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

With many thanks.

Elodie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that stems from compatibility with connectors other than community connectors. Usually a separate `getData` call is made for Summary fields in those cases.

This issue should get resolved in future. For the time being, the recommendation is to return a blank data object for `getData` calls with a blank `field` list.